# Run a specific rake test before running a specific test in RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rake, rake-task

I am testing an app with the built-in unit testing feature provided by rails. The problem is that one test heavily depends on calculations with ids and we must test that. As active record doesn't reset auto_increment when rolling back a transaction we are having some troubles here.

Things could be fixed if there is a way to reset all database tables and load the fixtures again as if I have run just that test.

Firstly I try to define a setup method to reset all the necessary auto_increment values in this way:

```
def setup
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("ALTER TABLE 'table_name1' AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;") 
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("ALTER TABLE 'table_name2' AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;")
end
```

but the test failed throwing this ugly error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
>   Mysql::Error: SAVEPOINT
>   active_record_1 does not exist:
>   ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1

Then I try to invoke db:test:prepare and db:fixtures:load in the setup method but this failed too. Besides, it will slow up the test a lot since the setup method is run before each test in the file, isn't it?

So how can I run those rake task just before a specific **test suite or test file** (don't know how to call it) and only for that one?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Please, explain a little bit more what you're trying to test. Maybe there's a better (and faster) way to test it than calling a rake task.

Comment: Ok. Specifically I want to test some methods that are in lib/file_i_want_to_test.rb. These methods are called by a rake task we have defined. The task gathers data from a table (let's call it parent table), does some calculation over that data, and fills child_table1. Now it gathers data from child_table1, does the calculations and fill child_table2... and so on until child_tableN. I could """fixed""" it altering the auto_increment id of a table, but it sucks. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to delete your test database, and then run `rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test` to recreate the database from within the test. If you do that in the middle of a test, however, you'll also need to re-seed the database with valid data, which can be a major pain in the ass, if that's the route you want to take.

You should also be able to use the "drop_table :table_name" stuff from migrations to do this.

**HOWEVER**, your tests shouldn't be written in such a way, nor should your DB be structured in such a way, they they rely on specific DB id's. Nor should your tests need to recreate whole tables just to reset the AUTO_INCREMENT value. This is almost certainly a sign that you're not using your test suite tools the way they are designed to be used. But, I also recognize that it's not a perfect world, and I'm hoping this is some kind of unusual edge case. :S

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [database_cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) gem. then on your database_cleaner.rb, you can specify `:pre_count` and `:reset_ids` to reset you ids. I recommend to use a separate database for your test environment as well.